# Creating Local Cache like memory

Tags: c#, dictionary, caching

As a part of a project I'm working on, I need to implement a cache like mechanism.

My cache is composed of 3 main things: Dictionary, List, File.

where the Dictionary needs to save the last 1000 items.

the list saves everything it can with its given memory
and at last we have the File to hold all items.

when I'd like to search from a range og items I need to look for like that:
Dictionary->List->File.
searching the file should be about 0%, since efficiency is required.

I'm trying to think about a proper function to search those last items (usually they are the ones that I need to extract)

for example one can request for items 1 to 1200 (searching the dictionary and then the list) and so on...

What is the best way to do this kind of search?

Comment: Have you tried anything that you can share?

Comment: Usually preferred method create a public class and pass an instance of the class within your application.

Comment: @smoksnes 
What do you mean by sharing?

Comment: @dan, if you have any code that you can provide in your question.

Comment: @smoksnes nope. this is pretty much what i can give :)

Comment: By which property you are going to Search??